# DataFormWebPart doesn't bring back all the items

Tags: 2010, data-form-web-part

I have a DataFormWebPart in a page that pulls items from a list. These items are filtered by a column for a specific value in that list.

In my scenario, I am expecting 20 items back but the web part always limits this to 10. I have tried it with other filter values which I expect other item counts with and it always limits it to 10.

Does anyone have an idea how I can get the web part to return all the items found for the applied filter?

I have included it below:

```
<WebPartPages:DataFormWebPart runat="server" Description="" PartOrder="2" HelpLink="" AllowRemove="True" IsVisible="True" AllowHide="True" UseSQLDataSourcePaging="True" ExportControlledProperties="True" DataSourceID="" Title="Answers" ViewFlag="8" NoDefaultStyle="TRUE" AllowConnect="True" FrameState="Normal" PageSize="30" PartImageLarge="" AsyncRefresh="False" ExportMode="All" Dir="Default" DetailLink="" ShowWithSampleData="False" ListId="d4b64c07-5c61-4946-8365-6252253ba81f" ListName="{D4B64C07-5C61-4946-8365-6252253BA81F}" FrameType="None" PartImageSmall="" IsIncluded="True" SuppressWebPartChrome="False" AllowEdit="True" ManualRefresh="False" ChromeType="None" AutoRefresh="False" AutoRefreshInterval="60" AllowMinimize="True" ViewContentTypeId="" InitialAsyncDataFetch="False" MissingAssembly="Cannot import this Web Part." HelpMode="Modeless" ID="g_4324ca3a_04e3_49c5_a94c_0394c973a7f9" ConnectionID="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" AllowZoneChange="True" IsIncludedFilter="" __MarkupType="vsattributemarkup" __WebPartId="{1BA05639-EAA5-4499-A7EB-21E7B1B3DE3D}" __AllowXSLTEditing="true" WebPart="true" Height="" Width=""><ParameterBindings>
                    <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_apos" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
                    <ParameterBinding Name="ManualRefresh" Location="WPProperty[ManualRefresh]"/>
                    <ParameterBinding Name="UserID" Location="CAMLVariable" DefaultValue="CurrentUserName"/>
                    <ParameterBinding Name="Today" Location="CAMLVariable" DefaultValue="CurrentDate"/>
                    <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_startposition" Location="Postback" DefaultValue=""/>
                    <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_firstrow" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
                    <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_nextpagedata" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
                    <ParameterBinding Name="Session" Location="QueryString(Session)" DefaultValue=""/>
                    <ParameterBinding Name="ListID" Location="None" DefaultValue="{D4B64C07-5C61-4946-8365-6252253BA81F}"/>
                    <ParameterBinding Name="NumberOfQuestions" Location="None" DefaultValue=""/>
                    <ParameterBinding Name="PassMark" Location="None" DefaultValue=""/>
                    <ParameterBinding Name="Discipline" Location="QueryString(Discipline)" DefaultValue=""/>
                    <ParameterBinding Name="LogonUser" Location="ServerVariable(LOGON_USER)" DefaultValue=""/>
                    <ParameterBinding Name="Passed" Location="Control(txtGrade, Text)" DefaultValue=""/>
                </ParameterBindings>
   <DataFields>@Title,Title;@AnswerGiven,AnswerGiven;@CorrectAnswer,CorrectAnswer;@Discipline,Discipline;@QuestionNumber,QuestionNumber;@SessionID,SessionID;@MarkAnswer,MarkAnswer;@ID,ID;@ContentType,Content Type;@Modified,Modified;@Created,Created;@Author,Created By;@Editor,Modified By;@_UIVersionString,Version;@Attachments,Attachments;@File_x0020_Type,File Type;@FileLeafRef,Name (for use in forms);@FileDirRef,Path;@FSObjType,Item Type;@_HasCopyDestinations,Has Copy Destinations;@_CopySource,Copy Source;@ContentTypeId,Content Type ID;@_ModerationStatus,Approval Status;@_UIVersion,UI Version;@Created_x0020_Date,Created;@FileRef,URL Path;@ItemChildCount,Item Child Count;@FolderChildCount,Folder Child Count;</DataFields>
<Xsl>
.....
</Xsl>
</<WebPartPages:DataFormWebPart>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you send the filter which you use to get data ?

And can you verify the default view of the list. I mean the default filter and limit rows ?

Comment: The view is set to 99 to limit per batch, and there are no filters on the view either. I am busy working on getting the xslt out as i have to use citrix to get in and they have blocked copy paste in a remote session.